# Catkin and Cython?

Tags: catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Has anyone tried cython with catkin? Some example?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/108776/catkin-and-cython?/) by [liborw](https://answers.ros.org/users/2302/liborw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 801 on 2013-12-09

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, there is an example of a guy using cython with catkin, look at his githup.
https://github.com/marcoesposito1988/cython_catkin_example

---

Originally posted by [pablocesar](https://answers.ros.org/users/20992/pablocesar/) with karma: 252 on 2015-12-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2